# How to translate "surface contamination"

Tags: traducción

I want to translate a phrase:

> Evaluation of surface contamination by beta radionuclides.

I have

> Evaluación de contaminación en superficies provocada por radio
>   nucleótidos  beta

I do not know if this is the correct use of **surface**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Evaluación de la contaminación **de** superficies por radioisótopos beta.

O bien

> Evaluación de la contaminación superficial por radioisótopos beta.

Comment: la traducción de radionuclides es radioisótopos ?

Comment: radioisótopo: Isotopo radiactivo de un elemento químico.

Comment: En escritos técnicos a veces se escribe radionucleido o radionúclido, pero no están en el DRAE. En cambio radioisótopo está en el DRAE y es de uso común. A menos que exista en inglés alguna diferencia entre radionuclide y "radioisotope", radioisótopo es más ortodoxo. En cualquier caso, nunca "radio nucleótido", los nucleótidos son los monómeros de los ácidos nucleicos (ADN y ARN).